# ASP.NET MVC : how to hold temporary data typed by user in create view of one controller while adding data in create view in other controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one model 1 with Name, Surname and IDAdress (this is foreign key to other model where I have Name of street, number...).

I create a controller and views (index, create, edit...) for for model 1 and model 2 (address). Then I go in create view for model 1 where user types Name, Surname and then it has link or button on create view for model 2.

My problem is when I type in data for Adresse and redirect after post in model 2 to view create of model 1 I lose Name and Surname that user already typed in.

I hope you understand what I want to ask. Do you have any idea how to solve this?

[Maybe this picture can help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9xZS.png)
Maybe this will help to understand. As you see I am leaving Create View 1 temporary so I can add info about address and after create in view create 2 I am going back to create view number 1. But if user typed in Name and Surname before adding address it has to type in that info again because I don't know how to hold that data temporary while I am adding address in view number 2.

Is there maybe a way where Create view 2 opens over create view 1 so it does not even close or I need to store type in data in some new table in database and then call those info when I am returning to view number 1...

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you are asking.  Perhaps you should add some code to your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I hope picture will help.

Comment: TempData, Session, Database, or a well-designed system using just viewModel objects...lots of options you can use to (temporarily) persist the state

Comment: Ty, I am new in programming, I will try now with TemData.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right you can merge your models in one big view model. Also you need to add hidden inputs to view for fields you want to pass.

Comment: TY. I will try with TemData, if it doesnt workout then I will try one big view model.

Comment: Of course TempData or Local Storage is a better way. :)